# Randomized Response, calculating probability

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-transformation, survey, proportion, probability-inequalities

I have a problem with randomized response method when calculating the probability of critical attribute. For any of you who are not familiar with the method, you can check it here, [Wikipedia Entry for Randomized Response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_response).

Briefly, the method encourages people being surveyed on a critical question to answer honestly. To achieve this, there are two questions whose answers are opposite to each other and respondents choose the first or second question with a probability of  *p* and *1-p*, respectively. The interviewer does not know which question is answered by the respondent, so the privacy of the respondent is preserved. As far as I know, this method is first studied by [Warner](http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1965.10480775#.Utz3ovT8JAs).

As you can imagine, the proportion of "yes" answers from the survey is composed (used conventions from Wikipedia)

```
YA = p*EP + (1-p)*(1-EP)
EP= (YA + p - 1) / (2*p-1)

YA: yes answers from survey,
EP: proportion of true yes answers
p: probability of answering critical questions
```

In my tests, for some cases the proportion of true yes answers is greater than 1.

Assume that, I get 55 yes answers out of 160 survey respondents and *p* is 0.4.

```
p=0.4
YA=0.34375 (55 out of 160)
EP= (YA + p - 1) / (2*p-1)
EP=(0.34375 + 0.4 - 1) /(2*0.4 - 1)
EP=(-0.25625)/(-0.2)=1.28125
```

Here, EP is greater than 1 which is not reasonable for a survey result because it means that more than survey respondents having such an attribute?(Am I wrong?). Is this result possible in this technique? Am I missing something? I wonder if anyone has any experience in this method and or any idea? How can I apply this method in order to get reasonable proportions for EP (0<=EP<=1)? I am totally confused about this method although it seem fairly reasonable to me.

I will appreciate your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the problem with the "method-of-moments" estimation: the estimate is unbiased, but is not restricted to the required parameter space. The Appendix of "Randomized Response: Theory and Techniques" by A. Chaudhuri, R. Mukerjee (can be found on Google Books) gives a corrected formula using the maximum likelihood estimate, which essentially sets the estimate to 0 or 1 depending on the exact situation (whichever gives the larger likelihood). This estimate is not unbiased, but most people would consider it more reasonable. In your case, I think the estimate would give $1$.

By the way, I think your main problem is the very high value of $p$. You should get it as far from $0.5$ as possible while still convincing people that you don't know which question they answered.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and suggestion. Then, I should take the conditions in that appendix into account and set my probability.

Comment: Would it be possible to put the formula here? I am unable to find that book in paper or ebook format.